# GLUE crawler run on RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have a use case where multiple schemas have the exactly same tables in a oracle rds instance. I need to catalog this rds instance. Occassionally the tables may have additional columns in a few schemas. The current crawler run creates table for each schema. Is their a way to merge table structure in this case via the crawler run. So what I want to achieve is that since all the schemas have the same table names and structures for most of the part, the crawler creates only 1 table for all the schemas rather creating multiple versions for the same table for each individual schema.